# Request line in HTTP request can be case sensitive?

Tags: http, httprequest, httpresponse

What if i give request where request line is in upper case & another request where request line is in lower case, does the server respond with same response in both the instances.

Comment: _"does the server respond with"_ - depends on the server and how it adheres to the relevant RFC's.

Answer (score 3):

All parts of the request line are case-sensitive. Lowercasing the method name will make it a different (unknown) method. Lowercasing the protocol name will make the request invalid. Lowercasing the URL will make it a request for a different resource.

Answer (score 2):

The URL is case sensitive. Unless your web server is running a case-insensitive operating system, or you have some rewriting going on with your web server. W3C would like them to be [considered case sensitive.](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html)

Comment: The HTML spec is totally irrelevant here.

Comment: Except for the part where they say "URLs in general are case-sensitive (with the exception of machine names)...Users should always consider that URLs are case-sensitive." which is a) totally relevant to the question, and b) just their opinion, which I made clear when I said "W3C would **like them** to be considered case sensitive."